# How do I exclude a list of values using a filter in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

In Google Sheets, I have a filter that does this:

```
=FILTER(A:K, B:B <> "username1")
```

That works to exclude all rows that have username1 in the B cell. But I want to exclude a list of usernames. So I tried:

```
=FILTER(A:K, (B:B <> "username1")+(B:B <> "unsername2"))
```

But that excluded nothing. I would have thought that filter should exclude all rows with either of those usernames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator corresponds with an `or` condition. Your test will yield true for any value, because a value is always different from either value1 or value2 or both, when value1 and value2 are not equal.

To make it work, use an `and` condition, like this:

`=filter(A2:K, B2:B <> "username1", B2:B <> "username2")`

Alternatively, put the usernames in range `R2:R` and use a `filter(match())` pattern like this:

`=filter(A2:K, isna(match(B2:B, R2:R, 0)))`